# Within my script, am I able to send emails from an email address that I have "send as" permissions for?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-api

I want to clarify that I am not a developer; my journey has involved using this site and chatGPT to the best of my ability. Kindly forgive any gaps in my knowledge, and I appreciate any insights you can provide.

I am currently working on a Google Script that involves sending reminder emails for subscription renewals using Gmail API, reading from a Google Sheet. I've made some progress but would appreciate some guidance.

Current Situation:

1. OAuth 2.0 Setup:

- Created a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID in the Google Cloud Console.
- Configured the OAuth consent screen and obtained a client ID and client secret.
- Updated the script with the correct client ID and client secret.

2. Redirect URI Issue:

- Initially encountered an "Access Blocked: Authorization Error," which was resolved by creating the correct redirect URI.

3. Library Access Issue:

- After fixing the redirect URI issue, encountered a "You do not have access to the library" error. I was able to resolve this issue and verified access to the library with the ID.

HELP!:
How can I "send as" an email address that is not my primary but I have "send as" permissions for? If anyone has experience with this or can provide insights into the correct implementation with Google Script, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have set up OAuth 2.0 and have gone through the authorization process. I don't know how to "send as" another email. Is this an additional code that I need to write in?

The script is functional as it will send the automated renewal email on a time-based trigger but I need the email to send from another email (not my primary).

I can share parts of my script.